# How to create insights from an excel file using either Python? I'm a beginner in both languages

Tags: python, r, excel, analytics

I have a large Excel spreadsheet which has lots and lots of historical data of an organisation. I want to be able to read that excel file and create valuable insights from it. I don't expect anyone to do this for me, but I'm just hoping someone can pinpoint me as to how should I go about doing this on Python/R or suggest any online resource I can access to get this done.

Comment: I think one of the best ways will be export the Excel file as a csv and then read it with the python csv library.
More info [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at openpyxl: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/.
It is great library for reading, writing and processing Excel spreadsheet in python. You can easily process the data and take valuable insights from it.